# Batch script terminates after executing JBoss CLI commands

Tags: batch-file, jboss

I am trying to execute a JBoss CLI commands in batch script to create a JBoss system property. The script terminates exactly after creating a system property.

I am using a property file[prop.properties] which contains a system property 'name' and 'value' to set in JBoss.
ex: `locate_property_file=c/user/desktop`

The CLI script looks like:

```
  if (outcome == success) of /system-property=locate_property_file:read-resource
 /system-property=locate_property_file:remove
 end-if

 if (outcome != success) of /system-property=locate_property_file:read-resource
  /system-property=locate_property_file:add(value=${locate_property_file})
 end-if
```

and then i am executing a jboss-cli.bat and passing the property file and .cli file as a argument:

```
%JBOSS_location%\bin\jboss-cli.bat -c --file=myscript.cli --properties=prop.properties
```

The batch script has much more commands to execute which well formed without syntax errors[tested without executing CLI] and it works fine. But after executing the cli script the batch script terminates without any prompt and it is was also able to create JBoss system property successfully.

Comment: added code styles

Comment: Is the issue that the rest of the script file is not executed? Have you tried turning on logging?